# Should dilaton field be at Planck energy everywhere?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, string-theory

I understand that the consensus view is that the dilaton field has been ruled out by solar system experiments like the time-delay measurements of the Cassini probe.

But surely that assumes the rest of the universe doesn’t interfere with the results of the experiment?

I would have thought that the sum of all interactions with masses $m_i$ throughout the universe drives the dilaton field $\phi$ up to the Planck energy at every point in space.

$$\phi^2\sim\sum_i \frac{m_i}{r_i} \rightarrow M^2_{Pl}$$

Comment: The string theory dilaton is massless. Unlike say the Higgs, It has no mass to be pushed up by interactions with other particles.

Comment: I’m hypothesising that the dilaton field is pushed up to the Planck scale rather than the mass of the dilaton itself.

Comment: Where would the energy from that come from? The dilaton field will have the same temperature as all the other fields i.e. basically zero. It would be close to its VEV almost everywhere. If the dilaton field had any significant energy it would quickly collapse the universe, and I think we would have noticed that.